# Is there a way to add parallelStream threads to existing Log4J2 context?

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm working on some large data processing, and am using a parallelStream on a collection to run this. Prior to the processing we have already added a configuration to the Log4J thread context. While it's running the processing, it is only logging the main thread to the file, but the other threads are not being written there.

I'm sure there is some way that the additional threads can be added to the same log file, but so far I have been unable to find the solution.

All of the processing is working correctly, the log is the last bit that I'm having an issue with, and am trying to resolve.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the Log4j2 answer to this is to put your tags into other contexts, rather than the thread context. They provide an extensible mechanism to define contexts based on things other than threads. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Custom_ContextDataInjector

Comment: I think you mix two concepts: the `ThreadContext` is basically a `ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>>` to store additional logging metadata. Loggers are associated with logger contexts using a [`ContextSelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ContextSelector). The default one uses the caller's classloader, it does not care about threads.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what I ended up having to do was to add to the ThreadContext for each of the common pool threads that were used in the parallelStream.

```
if (!Thread.currentThread().getName().startsWith(mainThread)) {              
    ThreadContext.put(BATCH_LOGGER_THREAD_CONTEXT_KEY, configuration);
}
```

This allowed the log lines to go to the expected file. I also had to remember to clean up the ThreadContext for the threads after the processing was complete so there wasn't any leakage into other logs.